# Mockito @InjectMocks Strategy

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, junit4

Yes, I know, much has been written about Mockito's @InjectMocks, but there is still a problem I haven't been able to solve...

Let's assume we have a class with four members...

```
class A {

    public B b1;
    public B b2;
    public B b3;
    public B b4;

}
```

...with `B` being an empty interface ...

```
interface B {

}
```

...then this setup will fail to initialize properly:

```
class MyTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private A a;

    @Mock(name = "b2")
    private B b2;  // will correctly be injected into field b2

    @Mock(name = "b4")
    private B b4;  // will be injected into field b3

    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks( this );
    }

    // some test here

}
```

Why? I have debugged the whole thing and found that it goes this way...

1. Search for a proper mock for field `b1`. Two candidates found with suitable types, so look for names. None of the names match. End. `b1` is empty, correct.
2. Search for a proper mock for field `b2`. Two candidates found with suitable types, so look for names. One of the names match. `b2` is filled correctly with the mock "b2".
3. Search for a proper mock for field `b3`. Only one candidate ("b4") is found with suitable types, so use that one. `b3` is incorrectly filled with mock "b4".
4. No mock left for field `b4`, will remain empty (incorrectly).

So, the only solution would be to add always one mock more than needed (so that for all needed mocks, there's always at least 2 candidates):

```
@Mock(name = "fakeyMcFakeFake")
private B fakeyMcFakeFake;
```

( Of course, fakeyMcFakeFake will be injected into field b1 in the second pass, but at least the other fields will be filled with the correct mocks ). But can this really be a solution? Has anyone an idea why this isn't handled better or how to handle it better?

( As for the use case... I have a controller that has various textboxes, etc. as members (those will be injected in the live code), obviously many of them are of the same type but for each test I will only need a small number of them.)

Comment: Can You also provide version of mockito which You use for this test? I recreated this situation with mockito-core in version 2.0.13-beta and it could not be reproduce. Unfortunately, until up to 2.0.13-beta it still occurs.

Comment: Ah, I am using 2.0.2-beta here, since that was the last version I found in maven central. But the problem there could be that I am using mockito-all instead of just mockito-core.

Comment: While using 2.0.13-beta works for one project, it doesn't work for another, since the PowerMock there needs mockito-all as a dependency (which isn't available above 2.0.2-beta. But thanks for the help, at least it works for one of my projects ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed in pull request [#215](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/pull/215) (see [release notes](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/master/doc/release-notes/official.md#2014-beta-2015-06-12-2018-utc)). I suspect your code is about an older version of mockito.

**While I like powermock I would advise to design code in a way that testing with mocks don't rely on powermock.**

Also for powermock, either upgrade to version 1.6.4 (just released) ; there's an issue ([#14](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/pull/14)) on powermock github repository that changes the dependency to `mockito-core`.
Otherwise please exclude `mockito-all` when declaring `powermock` dependency, `mockito-all` is a dependency for non-maven users (that still use the central repository). However I'm not sure future mockito 2.x beta will be compatible with current (1.6.x) powermock version.

Comment: I agree with the whole powermock thing. Actually, my project doesn't use it (since I don't like mocking statics), but another project over which I don't have control does ;-)